# Any good example to use requireJS in asp.net mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirejs

I have an asp.net mvc application (Not single page) and try to apply requireJS and look for good examples to apply the pattern. I have read a couple of blog posts, but didn't find any good examples. If you know any good examples or can offer some good advice, I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take a look at this one, I think its well explained.
https://web.archive.org/web/20150502094922/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1156/using-requirejs-in-an-aspnet-mvc-application

Comment: I really hope there is an example attached.

Comment: Looks like the author did attach an example later.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2012/09/intro-requirejs-for-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: I realize this is an older question, but another example also showing the build process for the RequrieJS optimizer on a multi-page MVC application (https://github.com/SparkSoftware/example-requirejs)

Comment: I'm here wondering.. the examples are for "static" pages, or by other means, pages that your application has. What could be an approach to handle dependencies for dynamic pages? For instance, let's say I have a page builder where the user creates and publish his own pages. How can require.js help in this scenario?

Comment: More resources, I found this gave a great explanation of how to marry the two together (bonus as he puts the entire solution up on github). Has a nice HtmlHelper too!) http://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2014/05/27/Adding-RequireJS-to-an-ASPNET-MVC-project

Comment: @Rayweb_on Your supplied link has been deactivated.

Comment: That link is still available in WayBack Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150502094922/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1156/using-requirejs-in-an-aspnet-mvc-application

Comment: As per SO guidelines, no links can be added without code samples to fix situation of website goes down.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference if it's ASP.NET MVC, Java, Ruby or anything else. JavaScript is a client side. I would say if you want to properly use RequireJS, forget minifiers, bundles and all that ASP.NET specific stuff. Have node on your build server and make it part of the build process to optimize using r.js.

I recently blogged about it: [**Understanding AMD & RequireJS**](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/understanding-amd-requirejs)

Comment: Interestingly this is exactly what they've done in MVC6. Removed bundling and implemented task based build processes using Gulp via NodeJS.

Comment: In particular it's what paths to use to reference the .js files from within an MVC View, are they relative to the view, the root, do they need to be calculated on the server... It's those types of questions that may need answering.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called [RequireJS.NET](http://requirejsnet.veritech.io/) that integrates RequireJS with MVC and allows setup of RequireJS through a config file that auto-outputs your configuration in your _Layout. You can install it via a Nuget package as well.

In my experience so far, it does what we need it to do, but there are some things that aren't clearly documentated, so it has taken us awhile to get it fully implemented. We have especially had issues understanding the Compressor, as the documentation is pretty light.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look that other http://blog.novanet.no/making-requirejs-play-nice-with-aspnet-mvc/ appear better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really good example of using RequireJS in a javascript MVC application:

http://verekia.com/requirejs/build-simple-client-side-mvc-app-require-js/

As Javascript is client side, it shouldn't make much difference which back end framework you are using, as Tomas said.